# C++ STL map/vector of vectors and thread safety

Tags: c++, boost, stl, thread-safety, containers

I was wondering whether following code would be considered thread-safe. I think it should be, but am not too familiar with what goes on under the hood.

Basically, I have this function in class Foo that will be called on the main thread and takes a vector as an anrgument, ie,

```
void Foo::func( vector<int> v)
```

In Foo, I also have a private member,

```
vector< vector<int> > vecOfVec;
```

Within `func`, I'll simply push back any new `v` onto `vecOfVec` and check for `v` 's size. If `v` is smaller than its expected size, I'd like to kick off another thread that fills up `v` with some known, predetermined values, like so

```
void Foo::func( vector<int> v)
{
    int size = v.size();
    int index = vecOfVec.size();

    vecOfVec.push_back(v);

    if (size < 1000)
    {
        boost::thread t( boost::bind( &Foo::PushBackZeros, this, vecOfVec, index) );
    }
}
```

`Foo::PushBackZeros` would, as its name suggests simply fill up the vector at 'vecOfVec[index]' with zeros until its size grows to 1000;

Now, I don't see any concurrent read or write operations here on any of the elements of `vecOfVec`. Obviously, there is a chance of concurrent operations on the entire object, but there will never be concurrencies on a particular element of `vecOfVec`.

Could someone explain as to whether the above would be considered thread-safe? Would the same extent to STL maps also? If not, please explain. Cheers!

Comment: what's the purpose of spawning another thread to call PushBackZeros?

Comment: the only assumption you should make about thread safety of the standard libraries (STL) is that they are *not threadsafe*, and program defensively as a result of that assumption.

Comment: This is just an idealized example. I was just interested in the more general case where you do operations on elements of STL containers where the elements won't be accessed/ read from/ written to by the main thread once they've been pushed onto it.

Comment: Multithreading is tricky and doing it without locks requires a lot of attention to all details. This means that you cannot trust that the answer to a synthetic idealized example will apply to your particular problem. In particular, different containers have different implementations, and operations on one element may have effects in others (removing the first element in a vector affects all other elements by moving them, adding an element at the end of the vector may make it grow and affect all others, insertion into a map can rebalance the tree and affect lookups in other threads...

Answer (score 8):

I think, that this is not thread-safe. What happens, if one thread pushes a new element onto the vector, which causes the vector's internal memory area to need to grow? The pushing thread might exchange the memory for a larger buffer, which can cause threads reading in parallel to this operation to suddenly read from invalid(ated) memory. Or threads seeing random values in certain slots, just because they read concurrently to the code which copies the contents of the vector from the old memory location to the new one.

Comment: Wow...thanks for the quick answer! I just posted this like 2 mins ago. I would have thought that this might be an issue, but wasn't sure. Thx!

Comment: The outer vector does not grow if you push members into an inner vector. sizeof(vector<T>) is fixed regardless of how many members it has.

Comment: @CashCow: I am referring here to the memory managed internally by the vector's implementation to hold the elements of the vector instance. The size of the `vector` instance does not change, but size and address of the memory area managed by it might.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Foo::PushBackZeros` has the same signature as `Foo::func( vector<int> v)`, then it will be thread safe, since you pass a copy of the array to that function. So there will be no concurrent access.

Comment: Good catch! You are right. Of course, elements added to the vector by the thread are lost that way (at least with respect to the world outside of the thread function)

Comment: I should have clarified: `Foo::PushBackZeros` would access vecOfVec as well. Actually there wouldn't have been a need to pass vecOfVec into `Foo::PushBackZeros`. I just cooked this up as an example.

Comment: Just be sure to use a reference if you want to modify that vector in a function...

Comment: Never mind the signature for PushBackZeros, boost::bind itself takes by value, so you need to boost::ref() your vecOfVecs to avert this.

Comment: Yes this would certainly be the way to do it and also how it's intended. It'd lead to concurrencies though, as Dirk suggested.

Answer (score 0):

vecOfVec is being passed by value because boost::bind requires you to put a boost::ref around a reference parameter.

So likely thread-safe but not doing what you think it is.

I am not sure why you need to pass that parameter in, as it is already in "this".

To answer the original question though for what you want to do:

- If vecOfVecs may be resized then any of its members could be invalidated so it would not be thread-safe.
- Pushing members into one of the inner vectors will not invalidate any other member vectors, so you could have different threads populating different vector members at the same time as long as they are all already there.
- If you "reserve" ahead then you can push_back more members into your vector until that capacity is reached and it won't invalidate existing members.

Comment: Yes. That parameter wouldn't have been necessary - negligence on my part there. I am still learning boost so I wasnt familiar with ref(). Thanks for the hint.

Comment: If I understand you correctly - if I, say, exchanged vector< vector<int>> with vector<int*>, new'ed every int* in vecOfVec to fixed size, then any operations I'd do within int* would be thread-safe?